# SAS Certification Queston

Tags: sas

Anyone knows why the response to this question is A.

Given the SAS data sets ONE and TWO:
The following SAS program is submitted:

```
Proc sql;
Select two.*,budget from one <insert JOIN operator here> two on one.year=two.year,
Quit;
```

The following output is desired:
Which JOIN operator completes the program and generates the desired output?

A. FULL JOIN
B. INNER JOIN
C. LEFT JOIN
D. RIGHT JOIN

Answer: A

Thanks for your time and inputs

Comment: What input? What output?

Comment: I'd suggest getting your SAS questions from a service like https://sasensei.com - where each question is explained, and you can comment directly on these kinds of issues

Answer (score 2):

You can answer this without seeing the data. The reason to chose FULL JOIN is when you want observations for values of `YEAR` that only appear in one of the datasets.